# Basic log4j example not working

Tags: log4j

Following is the contents of my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.main = INFO, main
log4j.logger.secondary = INFO, secondary

log4j.appender.main=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.main.File=C:\\Workspace\\test\\main.log
log4j.appender.main.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.main.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.main.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.main.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.secondary=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.secondary.File=C:\\Workspace\\test\\secondary.log
log4j.appender.secondary.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.secondary.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.secondary.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.secondary.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

This is how my main method looks:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Logger mainLogger = Logger.getLogger("main");
        final Logger secondaryLogger = Logger.getLogger("secondary");
        mainLogger.info("In main logger");
        secondaryLogger.info("In secondary logger");
    }
```

On executing this program, I am able to see the log messages in the Eclipse console, but I do not get my two log files created as expected.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Are you by any chance accidentally using java.util's logger?

Comment: @Ishnark Thanks for pointing that out! Yes, it had indeed used java.util.Logger. On changing it to org.apache.log4j.Logger, the program works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Ishnark, Eclipse had accidentally imported the incorrect `Logger` class. It had imported `java.util.Logger` instead of `org.apache.log4j.Logger`. On importing the appropriate `Logger` class (from `org.apache.log4j`), the program works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to define :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, main, secondary
```

instead of :

```
log4j.logger.main = INFO, main
log4j.logger.secondary = INFO, secondary
```